# How to convert a C++ struct to C# equivalent?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, dllimport

This is my C++ struct (the docs say that each instance has to be exactly 10 bytes in size):

```
#pragma pack (1)
struct LaserPoint {
    WORD x;
    WORD y;
    byte colors[6];
};
```

I made the following C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct LaserPoint {
    public UInt16 x;                   // 2 bytes
    public UInt16 y;                   // 2 bytes
    public byte[] colors;              // 6 bytes
}
```

Here's my full test code in my C# project:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace StructSizeTest {
    class Program {

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
        public struct LaserPoint {
            public UInt16 x;                   // 2 bytes
            public UInt16 y;                   // 2 bytes
            public byte[] colors;              // byte[6] = 6 bytes
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            LaserPoint point = new LaserPoint();
            point.x = (UInt16)16384;
            point.y = (UInt16)32768;
            point.colors = new byte[6];
            point.colors[0] = 255;
            point.colors[1] = 255;
            point.colors[2] = 255;
            point.colors[3] = 255;
            point.colors[4] = 255;
            point.colors[5] = 255;

            Console.WriteLine("LaserPoint.Size: " + Marshal.SizeOf(point));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the output on the console:

```
LaserPoint.Size: 8
```

Why is `point` 8 bytes in size and not 10 bytes?

```
UInt16  = 2 bytes
UInt16  = 2 bytes
byte[6] = 6 bytes
Total   = 10 bytes ?
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Because the array is not a compile-time fixed-size array. Think of it more like a pointer in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct LaserPoint {
    public UInt16 x;                   // 2 bytes
    public UInt16 y;                   // 2 bytes
    public byte[] colors;              // 6 bytes
}
```

`byte[] colors` is not 6 bytes wide. It is not even an actual array, but a reference to a byte array on the heap. Depending on your platform, it has either 32 bit (4 bytes) or 64 bit (8 bytes) in size (internally, it is a pointer). That is why you are getting a size of 8 bytes as a result (2 byte + 2 byte + 4 byte). On a 64 bit platform you would get a size of 12 bytes (2+2+8).

To have the `struct` behave like a C++ `struct` add the `MarshalAsAttribute` and specify `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` and `SizeConst`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct LaserPoint {
    public UInt16 x;                  
    public UInt16 y;                         
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public byte[] colors;             
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the array... Try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct LaserPoint {
    public UInt16 x;                   // 2 bytes
    public UInt16 y;                   // 2 bytes
    [MarhalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6]
    public byte[] colors;              // 6 bytes
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I decided to accept Adrian's answer as solution since he added some useful explanation. But I upvoted your's aswell.